# How to link to pdf as file with Java

Tags: java, jsp, pdf

Is there a way in Java/.jsp to set the content type, etc... so that a link to a pdf prompts the user to save it rather than opening it in the same or different window in the browser?  I've seen some examples of how to do this in PHP, but not Java.

Not sure if compiled vs. interpreted languages could have anything to do with why I can't find a Java solution. (Random thought)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the `Content-Type` and `Content-Disposition` headers. Assuming `response` is an `HttpServletResponse` object,

```
String filename = "foo.pdf";

response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
```

More info: [The BalusC Code: FileServlet](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/07/fileservlet.html).

Comment: This is an excellent start.  Yes, I'm forcing a "Save As" to a pdf through a link. The problem I'm running into now is I can't figure out how to set the path. I have the pdf stored in a separate folder on my webserver outside of the war file and need to navigate to that folder to load it.

Comment: @Chad: how to set which path? The path that the file is saved to on the browser's computer? You cannot control that.

Comment: The path of where the pdf resides on the server.  Inside my webapps folder in Tomcat, I have my war file for my application as well as a folder for files to download.  How do I specify that I want to look in that folder? i.e. "/downloads/sample.pdf"

Comment: @Chad: you'd use something like `InputStream input = getClass().getResourceAsStream("downloads/sample.pdf")` but I can't say what the exact path to the PDF would be since I don't know your directory structure.

Answer (score 3):

If the PDF is not autogenerated or read from an external location by a servlet, but just present in the public webcontent, then it suffices to map a `Filter` on an URL pattern of `*.pdf` (or whatever more specific/generic) which does the following job in the `doFilter()` method.

```
HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
String filename = req.getRequestURI().substring(req.getRequestURI().lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
res.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"");
chain.doFilter(request, response);
```

Answer (score 2):

You want to set a [Content-disposition](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/260519) header